# How might an ATC ask a pilot to check the weather conditions at a certain location?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, terminology

(Working on a translation that involves radio communications dialogue.)

Say the location is X nautical miles from the aircraft to a direction that's between the Y o'clock and Z o'clock direction, what might an ATC say over radio to ask a pilot to check the weather conditions the location?

Sorry and please let me know if the information is given in a strange format—that's the way it's presented in the source-language text.

**Edit:** The original text is in Chinese and goes something along the lines of:

> "[CALL SIGN]……您帮我看一下这儿天气，在您Y到Z点钟方位X海里这个地方。

for which a literal translation might go "[CALL SIGN], please check the weather here for me—X nautical miles at Y to Z o'clock."

The text is fictional and isn't meant to be technical, so it's possible that the phrasing doesn't match up with conventions. I just want to make sure I'm not translating it into something that's completely off-mark and would *never* be said in radio communications.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean to fly over and take a look?

Comment: What do you mean "*that's the way it's presented in the text*"?  What are you trying to "translate"?  Please provide source documents for a more complete answer, otherwise the short answer is for ATC to just ask for a PIREP.

Comment: @MichaelHall I'm sorry for being vague in my question. I've edited to provide more information. The source text is a fictional story and not any sort of technical document.

Comment: Much better, thanks.  Your literal translation is actually pretty good as-is.  I wouldn't quibble over it if I read it in a novel.  Sometimes radio communication is simply plain language, especially in slightly non-standard scenarios.

Comment: @MichaelHall Got it—thank you!

Comment: "Check the weather" is pretty vague. Is the controller asking about visibility, cloud base, precipitation, icing conditions, turbulence or something else entirely? It seems unrealistic that the controller does not specify exactly what information he is looing for.

Comment: Would ATC ever use “X o’clock” when communicating with an aircraft (except maybe while taxiing)? Wouldn’t they always use headings instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A controller would never ask an aircraft to go *out of its way* to check on weather, except in some emergency where the information is needed to help the other airplane with the emergency. Otherwise, it would only apply where the controller as asking for a pilot's observation from where they are, which is done from time to time.

A scenario might be, a VFR airplane stuck on top of a cloud layer, calls ATC for help, and a controller trying to help the pilot get down might ask an aircraft in the vicinity with a good vantage point if the area around location X is in the clear, so the controller could direct the VFR pilot to that area to get down.

If the situation is dire enough and some distance has to be covered to make the observation, the controller might even ask the pilot, if able, to divert to check it out, and it would be up to the pilot to do so.